# Implementing A* for solve a puzzle

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, a-star

I am trying to implement a A* algorithm for solve a sliding puzzle, but I can´t make the algorithm work, I have been working on this for the last few days but honestly I don´t know what's happen now. I have been following the pseudo-code from the Wikipedia and "RedBlobGame" blogs but now I'm completely lost.

This is de A* Algorithm

```
    ArrayList<Node> open = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Node> closed = new ArrayList<Node>();

    Node goal = new Node(myBoard.getGoalBoard());

    Node start = new Node(mb);
    start.setH(this.heuristic.calculate(start, goal));
    start.setG(0);
    start.setDepth(0);

    open.add(start);

    Node current = null;
    while(!open.isEmpty() && !myBoard.stopAlgorithm){
        current = getLowest(open);
        if(current.isGoal()){
            System.out.println("done");
            return finalise(current.getBoard(), displaySearch, current.getDepth());
        }
        open.remove(current);
        closed.add(current);
        int depth = current.getDepth() + 1;
        ArrayList<Node> succesors = current.getSuccessors(depth);
        for(Node node: succesors){
            node.setH(this.heuristic.calculate(node, goal));
            node.setG(current.getG() + 1);
            node.setParent(current);
            if(!closed.contains(node)){
                if(!open.contains(node)){
                    open.add(node);
                }else{
                    Node openN = open.get(open.indexOf(node));
                    if(node.getG() < openN.getG()){
                        openN.setG(node.getG());
                        openN.setParent(node.getParent());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("path not finded");
    return null;
```

Sometimes they find the solution and other times, just keep looking and expanding more possibles states, I can't see where is the problem. Any help on this?

This is the code from the Node class http://pastie.org/10521788
and the the calculus for the heuristic (manhattan in this case) http://pastie.org/10521789

Comment: Can you post the MyBoard class?

Comment: I can´t because is not my code, but the MyBoard class hold the grid (2D array of ints) and the parent instance adn a few more things, not revelant for the A* (I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just a guess. It has been a while since I coded A* and I can't see how you implemented the node class. I don't think you should set G with node.setG(current.getG()+1) or set the parent to current if node is already added to the open list.

try :

```
int depth = current.getDepth() + 1;
ArrayList<Node> succesors = current.getSuccessors(depth);
for (Node node : succesors) {
    if (!closed.contains(node) && !open.contains(node)) {
        node.setH(this.heuristic.calculate(node, goal));
        node.setG(current.getG() + 1);
        node.setParent(current);
        open.add(node);
    } 
}
```

This is a more complete version that seems to work for me (only tested with 3 x 3. Most of the code is just setting up the state. Somethings to note: For efficiency you don't want to have to search a list to see if a state is contained in it. It is better to use a HashSet but that requires implementing hashCode() and equals() consistently. Your IDE can probably generate them.

```
public static class BoardState {

    int positions[];

    private int priority;

    /**
     * Get the value of priority
     *
     * @return the value of priority
     */
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of priority
     *
     * @param priority new value of priority
     */
    public void setPriority(int priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    private int distFromGoal;

    /**
     * Get the value of distFromGoal
     *
     * @return the value of distFromGoal
     */
    public int getDistFromGoal() {
        return distFromGoal;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of distFromGoal
     *
     * @param distFromGoal new value of distFromGoal
     */
    public void setDistFromGoal(int distFromGoal) {
        this.distFromGoal = distFromGoal;
    }

    private BoardState goal;

    /**
     * Get the value of goal
     *
     * @return the value of goal
     */
    public BoardState getGoal() {
        return goal;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of goal
     *
     * @param goal new value of goal
     */
    public void setGoal(BoardState goal) {
        this.goal = goal;
    }

    private int depth;

    /**
     * Get the value of depth
     *
     * @return the value of depth
     */
    public int getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of depth
     *
     * @param depth new value of depth
     */
    public void setDepth(int depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    private BoardState prev;

    /**
     * Get the value of prev
     *
     * @return the value of prev
     */
    public BoardState getPrev() {
        return prev;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of prev
     *
     * @param prev new value of prev
     */
    public void setPrev(BoardState prev) {
        this.prev = prev;
    }

    public BoardState(BoardState other) {
        this.positions = new int[9];
        System.arraycopy(other.positions, 0, this.positions, 0, positions.length);
        this.depth = other.depth + 1;
        this.goal = other.goal;
        this.prev = other;
    }

    private BoardState() {

    }

    public static BoardState goal() {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        IntStream.range(0, 9).forEach(i -> l.add(i));
        BoardState r = new BoardState();
        r.positions = new int[9];
        Arrays.setAll(r.positions, i -> l.get(i).intValue());
        return r;
    }

    public static BoardState random() {
        List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        IntStream.range(0, 9).forEach(i -> l.add(i));
        Collections.shuffle(l);
        BoardState r = new BoardState();
        r.positions = new int[9];
        Arrays.setAll(r.positions, i -> l.get(i).intValue());
        return r;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 83 * hash + Arrays.hashCode(this.positions);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final BoardState other = (BoardState) obj;
        if (!Arrays.equals(this.positions, other.positions)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    int valueAt(int r, int c) {
        int pos = r * 3 + c;
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            if (pos == positions[i]) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("invalid board or position");
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.println("depth = " + depth);
        for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
                System.out.print(this.valueAt(r, c) + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }

    }

    int distance(BoardState other) {
        int dist = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < positions.length; i++) {
            int c0 = this.positions[i] % 3;
            int r0 = this.positions[i] / 3;
            int c1 = other.positions[i] % 3;
            int r1 = other.positions[i] / 3;
            dist += Math.abs(r0 - r1) + Math.abs(c0 - c1);
        }
        return dist;
    }

    public List<BoardState> moves() {
        List<BoardState> newList = new ArrayList<>();
        int r0 = this.positions[0] / 3;
        int c0 = this.positions[0] % 3;
        if (r0 > 0) {
            BoardState up = new BoardState(this);
            up.positions[0] = (r0 - 1) * 3 + c0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                if (this.positions[i] == up.positions[0]) {
                    up.positions[i] = this.positions[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            newList.add(up);
        }
        if (r0 < 2) {
            BoardState down = new BoardState(this);
            down.positions[0] = (r0 + 1) * 3 + c0;
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                if (this.positions[i] == down.positions[0]) {
                    down.positions[i] = this.positions[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            newList.add(down);
        }
        if (c0 > 0) {
            BoardState left = new BoardState(this);
            left.positions[0] = r0 * 3 + (c0 - 1);
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                if (this.positions[i] == left.positions[0]) {
                    left.positions[i] = this.positions[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            newList.add(left);
        }
        if (c0 < 2) {
            BoardState right = new BoardState(this);
            right.positions[0] = r0 * 3 + (c0 + 1);
            for (int i = 1; i < 9; i++) {
                if (this.positions[i] == right.positions[0]) {
                    right.positions[i] = this.positions[0];
                    break;
                }
            }
            newList.add(right);
        }
        for (BoardState move : newList) {
            move.setDistFromGoal(move.distance(goal));
            move.setPriority(move.distFromGoal + move.depth);
        }
        return newList;
    }
}
```

The actual A* is relatively short:

```
BoardState goal = BoardState.goal();
System.out.println("goal");
goal.print();
BoardState start = BoardState.random();
System.out.println("start");
start.print();
start.setGoal(goal);
start.setDistFromGoal(start.distance(goal));
start.setPriority(start.distFromGoal + start.depth);
PriorityQueue<BoardState> open = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparing(b -> b.getPriority()));
open.offer(start);
Set<BoardState> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(start);
int round = 0;
while (!open.isEmpty()) {
    BoardState cur = open.poll();
    round++;
    if (cur.equals(goal)) {
        System.out.println("goal found after " + round + " rounds");
        System.out.println("printing boards in reverse order");
        do {
            cur.print();
        } while (null != (cur = cur.getPrev()));
        break;
    }
    for (BoardState move : cur.moves()) {
        if (!set.contains(move)) {
            set.add(move);
            open.offer(move);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the code for the Node class http://pastie.org/10521788. I trit you inplementation but still looping and expanding nodes. I am completly lost just not